# Call a different component template on mouseover

Tags: html, angular, components, string-interpolation

I got to create components, retrieve data from API's, used *ng directives, and so on...

Now I'm blocked with something that goes beyond my understanding.

## App Behaviour

I've got two components, one is **hand** (parent) and the other is **card** (child).

**Hand** has 5 "div" elements with little data (randomly picked), provided by a Service API (getAllCards()) (Image below):

[image]

**Card** is a single "div" that, on mouseover a element from **Hand**, should show more extensive data from the same Service as Hand, but different API function (getCardById(parameter data-id of card in div hand))(Image below):

[image]

## Components & Code

#### card-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CardDataService {

  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {
    
  }

  getAllCards() {
    return this.httpclient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/cards');
  }

  getCardById(id: number) {
    return this.httpclient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/cards/'+id);
  }
}
```

#### card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CardDataService } from '../../services/card-data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],

})

export class Card implements OnInit{

    // OBJECT
    public item?: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCardData();
    }

    // GET DATA FROM NODEJS API
    
    public getCardData(id: number) {
        this.cardDataService.getCardById(id).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.item = response;
    });
    }
}
```

#### card.component.html

```
<div class="card-display">
  <p>CARD {{ item.id }}</p>
  <p>LEVEL {{ item.level }}</p>
  <img src="{{ item.picture }}>
  <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
  <div class="card-stats">
    <label>{{ item.attack }}</label>
    <label>{{ item.defense }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### hand.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CardDataService } from '../../services/card-data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],

})

export class HandComponent implements OnInit{

    // OBJECT
    hand: any[] = [];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCardData();
    }

    // GET DATA FROM NODEJS API
    
    public getAllCards() { // Get 5 random "Card" from the result
        this.cardDataService.getAllCards().subscribe((response: any) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(response).length);
                this.hand.push(Object.values(response)[randomIndex]);
            }

            console.log(this.hand);
        });
    }
}
```

#### hand.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of hand">
  <div class="card-hand">
    <p data-id="{{ item.id }}">CARD {{ item.id }}</p>
    <img src="{{ item.picture }}">
    <p>{{ item.element }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

#### API (getAllCards)

```
[
  {
   id: 1,
   level: 7,
   picture: "assets/images/1.png",
   element: "FIRE",
   description: "S4",
   attack: 9000,
   defense: 7000
  },{
   id: 2,
   level: 3,
   picture: "assets/images/2.png",
   element: "WATER",
   description: "S9",
   attack: 2000,
   defense: 1000
  },{
   id: 3,
   level: 15,
   picture: "assets/images/3.png",
   element: "WATER",
   description: "S1",
   attack: 13000,
   defense: 9000
  },{
   id: 4,
   level: 6,
   picture: "assets/images/4.png",
   element: "WIND",
   description: "S5",
   attack: 6000,
   defense: 3000
  },{
   id: 5,
   level: 9,
   picture: "assets/images/5.png",
   element: "FIRE",
   description: "S3",
   attack: 9000,
   defense: 8000
  }
]
```

## How Can I Do It?

What I'd like to do is, on hovering (**onmouseover**) a card from hand, render the card.component.html and, (**onmouseleave**) remove that renderization.

I don't know the approach to take on this subject, I've tried the @Input directive but I couldn't figure out how to pass the attribute "data-id" from ".card-hand" to access it on another component and render that component's HTML.

Maybe having a variable with all the HTML tags and render it on from the hand component (I also don't know how to render), also I don't think that's the best way either...

Could you guys please give me a helping hand? I'll be up to reply any questions regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is adding templates `ng-template` to the tooltip. but you would need a library that supports adding template, example: [ng bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#tplcontent)
here is a quick example

```
<ng-template #tipContent>// this is how you nam the template #<any-name>
   <any-angular-component-you-want></any-angular-component-you-want>
</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent">
    I've got markup and bindings in my tooltip!
</button>
```